# Vote counter appearing in center of the screen

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

- Browser: Microsoft Edge
- Version: 40
- Platform Windows
- Issue: See the vote counter

[image]

Comment: Try to update Edge. [SE only supports "_the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use._"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: It seems more like they are actively pursuing to *not* support older browsers.

Comment: More like they are actively using modern CSS and HTML, @usr2564301 ;).